# PHP cURL doesn't include host http header

Tags: php, curl

PHP's curl doesn't seem to include the Host header when doing a request:

```
<?php
    $handle = curl_init('http://example.com/');
curl_setopt_array($handle, array(
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'test ua',
    CURLOPT_REFERER => 'http://example.org/',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_PROXY => '127.0.0.1:8080',
    CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_HTTP,

    //Doesn't work if you specify it manually or leave it out:
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Host: example.com'
    )
));

print_r(curl_getinfo($handle));
echo curl_exec($handle);
?>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not including the host header? It always will because it is a requirement of HTTP 1.1, what makes you think it isn't doing it?

Comment: @DaveRandom I'm using Charles web debugging proxy and I can see that it isn't included there.

Comment: That is very odd - is it using HTTP/1.0? Try forcing cURL to use HTTP/1.1 with `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1`, try this even if it currently shows 1.1 I would suggest. PHP/libcurl version?

Comment: Also if you *don't* use the proxy do you still get the 400 from the page suggested by Matchu below?

Comment: @DaveRandom It was using HTTP/1.1, please see my answer.

Comment: can you restart the machine? Just in case...

Comment: @WalterToss Yeah, see my answer on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a totally unrelated bug, which happened by having a linebreak inside the user-agent, eg.:

```
curl_setopt_array($handle, array(
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "user-agent\n"
));
```

Comment: Ah right. Yes that will break it. Although I'm surprised cURL doesn't sanitise for that, and if you were looking at the request in a debugging proxy I would have though that would be immediately obvious, but hey... For future reference, you should always post as close to you actual code as possible in questions, change usernames/passwords and (if you must) URLs *only* as it's often a problem that you can't see but someone else will spot immediately - because you edited the UA assignment we couldn't see it. But glad you sorted it out :-)

Comment: @DaveRandom You couldn't see it in the request, as the raw request was 3 lines, where line 1 was `GET http://example.com/` and line 2 was `User-Agent: test ua` and the third line was empty.

Comment: Yes, but if you had looked at the body you would have seen the remaining headers, since that's basically what they were because of the extra `\n`. Unless Charles doesn't show you the body because a GET shouldn't have one - but if that is the case it's frankly not a brilliant debugging tool. For network level stuff I use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) because you are examining the raw TCP packets and not an application layer interpretation of what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

Host header is defined by the argument of [curl_init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)()

Comment: It doesn't send **any** host header!

Comment: How do you know? curl_getinfo() would not tell you that. What do print_r(curl_getinfo($handle)); and echo curl_exec($handle); return?

Answer (score 0):

The `Host` header is already automatically by PHP when you specify the request URL.

The following example oughta be sufficient confirmation:

```
<?php
$handle = curl_init('http://pgl.yoyo.org/http/browser-headers.php');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

echo curl_exec($handle);
?>
```

The output HTML lists the request headers, among which we see `Host: pgl.yoyo.org`, as expected.

Comment: I get `400 Bad Request`, as the host isn't included as I said.